# Heroku app Does not Upload Files to S3 in Ruby with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, rubygems, paperclip

I followed precisely [this link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3#configuration) to set up AWS S3 for my heroku app:https://feedimg.herokuapp.com/pins

Have done extensive research but I can not figure out why the uploaded images are still not linked or stored in S3.

Comment: ill clone your repo and see if i can fix it

Comment: Have you set read/write privileges in your s3 bucket?

Comment: @mrvncaragay here is my github repo: https://github.com/leonahu/IMGfeed

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work. I have deployed the app through Heroku. you can check it [here](https://shielded-sierra-73642.herokuapp.com/pins) notice that if when you view the source of the image it saves to s3.

Also you can check out the repo on my [github](https://github.com/mrvncaragay/IMGfeed) and compare it to your repo.

let me know if you manage to make it work.

Comment: Thank you! I was comparing the code, it looks like I misplaced IMGfeed to Webapp? Could you elaborate your changes. Thanks again!

Comment: some changes like `Paperclip.options[:command_path]...` was recommended to avoid spoofing. i also use the newest version of paperclip. i added the `Procfile` since heroku reccommend that we use `Puma` and what did you put in your `AWS_REGION`?

Comment: I put us-west-2, which is Oregon.

Comment: also make sure in your s3 bucket you add permission to everyone `list and upload/delete`

Comment: I think i found a new problem as I was trying to push it to Heroku:remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: ! Push rejected to feedimg.
remote:

Comment: the S3 permission is set to everyone, AWS region is updated as well as paperclip gems.

Comment: i think i had that problem too. did you configured you aws keys... before pushing?